# Qualtrics: Calling javascript variable inside CSS using ${variable } not working

Tags: javascript, css, qualtrics

I am going crazy with this so your help will be enormously appreciated.

I have this javascript function:

function fillColor(){

percent1 = (sliderOne.value / sliderMaxValue) * 100;

percent2 = (sliderTwo.value / sliderMaxValue) * 100;

sliderTrack.style.background = `linear-gradient(to right, #dadae5 ${percent1}% , #3264fe ${percent1}% ${percent2}%, #dadae5 ${percent2}%)`;

for some reason the ${percent1} and ${percent2} calls don't work. Everything is fine when I substitute that for actual nubmers though.

What drives me insane is that it works we all when previewing the question, but not when previewing the survey/block! Is ther something about how qualtrics reads the javascript with the ${} language? I have barely any other code in the survey that could be interacting with this, so don't think that's what's gonig on.

Thanks in advance. So much

Comment: can you set a mimal code snippet reproducing your issue ? `${percentX}` may not be avalaible from where you call them

Comment: Thanks for responding! (a) console.log(percent1) works, (b) the whole thing previews perfectly if I preview the Qualtrics question alone, but not when I preview the survey/block. So it must be something about how Qualtrics does it. 
I also don't know how to create a snippet.
I'm desperate here.

Comment: Your color stops are defined wrongly: you are missing a color for one of the stops. Your answer works because you’ve added the missing color. Not because you stopped using template literals.

Comment: I saw you already answered your own question, but in Qualtrics ${} is a piped field that gets resolved on the server before the page is sent to the browser. In your case they would have been blanks because ${percent1} isn't a valid piped field. A valid field would be something like ${e://Field/percent1}.

Comment: Thanks for that, Gibbons. I wasn't sure what solution would work to get around that, until I tried the answer below. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using this:

```
function fillColor(){

   percent1 = (sliderOne.value / sliderMaxValue) * 100;

   percent2 = (sliderTwo.value / sliderMaxValue) * 100;

  colores = `linear-gradient(to right, #ADD8E6 ` + percent1 + `%, #3264fe ` + percent1 + `%, #3264fe ` + percent2 + `%, #DC143C ` + percent2 + `%)`;

   sliderTrack.style.background = colores;

 }
```